# Criação de uma nova tag - RFID

Tags: suporte, tags

Não sei quantos que frequentam esse site têm questões e respostas relacionadas a RFID, já que o assunto é bastante amplo com um número significativo de aplicações. Eu mesmo vim aqui agora com a intenção de fazer uma pergunta específica sobre o assunto, porém não achei a tag.

Não seria o caso de cria-la? Já que se trata de uma questão específica e pode estar relacionada tanto à linguagem Delphi, C#, Android, etc, portando não é uma questão relacionada à linguagem especificamente e sim à aplicação.

Answer (score 6):

Hoje qualquer usuário com pelo menos 300 pontos de reputação pode criar uma tag, para isso basta criar uma pergunta utilizando-a, e pronto, ela está criada.

Veja mais informações na página de privilégios: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags